Meaning of は and が here?

ねえ、田中さんがもう一度会ってほしいって。田中さん、犬のこと考え直したんだって。犬飼っていいって。だから、会ってあげれば？
いや、無理。私もう田中さんに会う気はないの。だから伝えて、「私はもうあなたに会う気がない」って。

Why does it change from 気はない to 気がない in the message that should be passed on?
Is it 1) because は is used as contrastive (something beside meeting is okay) and が is a simple statement or is it the other way around?
2) That は is just a simple statement here and が is used in its exhaustive-listing function to emphasize that one does not want to meet?
Source

This is one of the uncommon cases where が and は are interchangeable.

In general, が is used in the AはBが construction such as 彼は背が高い and 象は鼻が長い. 彼は背は高い would be interpreted as a contrastive sentence meaning "He is at least tall (despite having some shortcomings)". Compare them with 彼の背は高い and 象の鼻は長い, which are neutral statements.
However, は is generally preferred in negative sentences. Why is the topic marker often used in negative statements (ではない, ～とは思わない)?

As a result, 私は彼に会う気はない and 私は彼に会う気がない are both natural, and there is almost no difference between them.
However, note that:

If there was no explicit topic (私(は)), the difference between 会う気がない and 会う気はない could be a little more noticeable. For details, please see my answer here: Which は is this?
If the sentence was non-negative, you always have to say 私は彼に会う気がある. 私は彼に会う気はある would suddenly become a contrastive sentence, for example "I am at least willing to see him (but I'm not going to listen to his advice)".


I might have phrased my questions poorly. He first said 私もう田中さんに会う気はないの。 with a は but changed it at だから伝えて、「私はもうあなたに会う気がない」って。 to が. I was wondering what the meanings of these two are because I thought there is a reason for changing it instead of using both times は/が. I didn't want to know how the meaning would change if 私はもうあなたに会う気がない is changed to 私はもうあなたに会う気はない.
Or am I just misunderstanding your answer and the neutral statement still applies to both?

@Khal No reason. She just said whichever occurred to her first. It could have been 私もう田中さんに会う気がないの。だから伝えて、「私はもうあなたに会う気はない」って。, or she could have used either が or は for both places. There's no difference in meaning.

Thank you for the explanation.
